# Win 7 Explorer quickview pane doesn't work with JPEG files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Content just is the same as title.
Any suggest are appreciated!
[image: Win7 Explorer Quick View Pane doesnt work]

---

And all setting on my PC are default except the GUI (I like Windows Classic GUI).
[image]

Comment: Looks like you've assigned the .jpg file extention to a program which has stopped Windows from being able to preview them.

Comment: @HaydnWVN should be an answer.

Comment: @HaydnWVN
no i don't
see image link for evidence
http://i.imgur.com/BIaJO.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tools->Folder Options, under the View tab, make sure "Always Show Icons, Never Thumbnails" is unchecked.