# Thumbnails not showing, cannot preview images, sometimes folders do not show up at all

Tags: windows, thumbnails

When I try to preview images, nothing happens.

Sometimes, all/most thumbnails do not show a preview and only show up as an icon.

Sometimes when I open 'My Computer' or 'My Documents' etc. the folders don't appear at all unless I reopen it a few times until they show up.

What can I do?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I assumed Windows since "My Computer" is pretty self-explaining.

Comment: Windows 7 of course, I thought this forum was for windows 7 anyway.

Comment: Possibly could be this:  http://superuser.com/questions/392289/win-7-explorer-quickview-pane-doesnt-work-with-jpeg-files/392608#392608

Comment: the thumbnails appear when a scroll up and down really fast so i know they are there, they don't seem to be appearing

Comment: thanks adam, but i have tried that solution and it doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: I really don't know why you need to be so rude against me. Your question got two downvotes, probably because it lacked detail, and I was just pointing out to you that you might get a better response if you added more information. That's all, just trying to help you get a better response.

Comment: i'm sorry, i do apologize, its just this problem has been bugging me for ages, plus i broke up with my boyfriend the otherday, even though we're on the internet i still didn't mean to be rude, take my apology

Comment: Sure, apology accepted. Welcome to Super User, by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you affect some picture file extensions (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp etc...) with any software that you have uninstalled? If yes, you can re-install that software to get back your thumbnails, or you can change your file extension settings by using Control Panel.

Comment: Which software would I have had to download to affect this? You sound like you know what the problem is, please help. How do you change file extensions and what would I have to change it to?

Comment: I had experienced this problem before, not with the pictures but with the video files. You can first try to restore to default settings by using this article (How to Change File Extension in Windows 7) : http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-change-file-extension-in-windows-7/ .If it does not work, you can try to install a software like Irfanview (http://www.irfanview.com/) etc... I hope it solves your problem.The last option is to reinstall your operating system.

Comment: this provided the fix thank you NT x i can't believe someone actually managed to help :)

Comment: you're welcome, I'm happy that solved your problem...

Answer (score -2):

Go into your Documents folder (windows explorer) and in the Tools menu select |Folder options and go to the View tab. In the bottom right click Restore Defaults or (just) Default and hit Apply. This should set your thumbnails back and have the folders img show the files

Comment: Please, out of respect for people who are reading your communications: Use punctuation and capitalization. Reading stream-of-consciousness is really hard.